# Firebase validation basic integer comparison fails in simulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase for a while but never used validate property till now, I cannot understand a reason for why this simple validation fails (Tried several variations as well as '0' in data/rules/both)

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, I changed to:
".validate": "newData.val().mutex1==0",
and it fails with:Simulation failed - Line 9: No such method/property 'mutex1'.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the correct is `".validate" : "newData.child('mutex1').val() == 0"`

Comment: You have to use a wildcard for that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to input a wildcard under your mutexes path.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "selenium_tasks":{
        "mutexes":{
          "$mutex":{
            ".validate": "newData.val() == 0",
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

[image]

For more information : [Firebase Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)